Android Studio annoying line pasting issue
I'm having troubles with Android Studio after switching to a new pc. When I'm trying to paste a whole line at the end of another one, it's inserted on a line above the one, the caret is standing on
For example, in this code:
val foo: Foo = Foo()
val bar: Bar = Bar()

If I place the caret on the val bar: Bar = Bar() line and press Ctrl+C I'm saving the line to clipboard. Then I'm placing the caret at the end of the val foo: Foo = Foo() line and press Ctrl+V and I'm expecting this:
val foo: Foo = Foo()val bar: Bar = Bar()
val bar: Bar = Bar()

But I get this instead:
val bar: Bar = Bar()
val foo: Foo = Foo()
val bar: Bar = Bar()

Please help
I tried searching google for any answers and only found one question with a totally opposite problem: How to paste on separate line in Android Studio?
